# Android SyncAdapter: synchronize at a certain hour

Tags: android, synchronization, android-syncadapter

I have an application that uses a `SyncAdapter` to synchronize some data with a server once a day. I want the user to be able to select the hour when this synchronization is performed. The user can change this hour whenever he wants.

In this scenario, what should I do?

1- Use a `Receiver` to call `requestSync` at the selected hour.

2- Define a 24 hours periodic sync.

In the solution number 2 I'm not sure how could I update the hour to request the sync if the user modifies it. If I use `addPerodicSync(account, AUTH, params, 24*HOURS);` would it perform a synchronization every day at the hour I set the periodic sync?

Thanks!